# Retag Facebook Open Graph related tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggest/ Merge Tag Synonym [facebook-opengraph] -> [opengraph]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127385/suggest-merge-tag-synonym-facebook-opengraph-opengraph)

[open-graph-protocol](/questions/tagged/open-graph-protocol), [facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) and [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) are obvious duplicates.

It has been suggested (by [Mat](/users/158667/mat)) that I should have specified the master. I would agree with him that [facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) should probably be the master tag.

Comment: @Mat: Thank you for that edit; I didn't realise you could do that `[tag: ... ]` format for tags. We learn something new every day  :o)

Comment: If you ever want to talk about meta tags, you can do [meta-tag:unicorns] too. (BTW: from what I've seen, it's good to specify which tag should become the "master tag" when you do requests like this. Prob. facebook-opengraph here.)

Comment: Ah, good point — I've edited to add that suggestion. The comment box doesn't show me how you did that meta tagging, though  ;o)

Comment: @phwd Surely that one is a duplicate of this one, given I asked this question three months before that one?  ;o)

Comment: Well the idea of getting a mod to set [status-declined] to this one too and for me to answer it seemed like a bit more work.

Comment: @phwd Fair point :)