# Suggest/ Merge Tag Synonym [facebook-opengraph] -> [opengraph]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I want to suggest [facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) for [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) on http://StackOverflow.com. 
Both have same meaning.

[facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) has 365 questions.

[opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) has 514 questions.

Comment: It's a sponsored tag. A synonym/merge could have unintended consequences.  Checking with management...

Comment: ...Check completed.  Negative; they mean two different things.  OpenGraph is [not Facebook-specific](http://ogp.me/).

Comment: Then why [tag:opengraph] tag have `f` in it?

Comment: Facebook paid SE some money to put it there.  That's what "sponsored tag" means.  Anyone can sponsor any tag, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) refers to the protocol originally created for Facebook (though most users have been tagging them with both)

For example, [Google Plus accepts this protocol](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet).

[facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) refers to the Open Graph specifically in relation with Facebook Graph API.

I suppose one should change the descriptions of these tags as to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Then `f` should have been removed from opengraph tag.

Comment: @Som: The `f` indicates that [tag:opengraph] is a sponsored tag. Facebook has paid to put their `f` on that tag. See [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) for more information.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk It does give confusion but it is Facebook who started up the OG Protocol so yeah I think if they wanted to sponsor the tag it should be okay. For now the tag info needs to be changed for opengraph